# How to do random mouse click and motion

Tags: vbscript, mouseevent, batch-processing

I want to move my mouse to different locations on an active screen and also want to perform mouse actions, i.e. right click or left click. I have already tried

```
Set ab = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.SendKeys("{ClickRight x,y}"
```

Where x and y are coordinates, but it's not working.

Comment: I like wishful programming. But it never works. You cannot control a mouse with VBScript. You are aware that anything that can be done by mouse should be able to be done by keyboard. EG Shift + F10 is contest menu. TAB changes focus, etc.

Comment: You have to make WIN32 API calls to control the mouse.  Do to poor documentation it's very difficult to implement.  Like Noodles said there is probably a better way.

Comment: Perhaps you could detail what it is you're trying to achieve and we can help you find a way to make it happen.